# Server 2008 R2 vs ASA5505

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, cisco-asa

We have a cisco asa5505 and we run DHCP through a server 2008 R2 box. I did an 80/20 rule with another server 2008 RU machine (on this network) but when the primary server went down it did not engage/populate the DHCP settings to clients and we were down for 30 minutes.

What is your opinions on running it through a server 2008 R2 box or running the DHCP from the asa5505? we went server 2008 because it is a little more flexible.

Thanks!

Comment: What were the exact circumstances related to the outage, because a DHCP client doesn't release it's ip address when the DHCP server goes down. I'm at a loss to see how the DHCP server being down for 30 minutes caused the problems you experienced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would guess that you didn't have BOOTP/DHCP forwarders set up on your L3 switches/firewall, so clients couldn't get to the second server. I wouldn't run DHCP on my firewall unless there were no other alternative. In this case, I would recommend isolating what exactly broke your configuration with 2008R2 and fix that.

Comment: +1 Find the real problem and fix it